# How to play a video file from a particular timstamp in opencv using python?

Tags: python, opencv

The user gives an input of start time and end time(timestamps) in a video. The video file should be played within that time parameter, and not the whole thing. 
Any help would be appreciated.

I have 2 hour long video file, i just want to play the video where key events took place.

Comment: take a look to [set](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.6/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a8c6d8c2d37505b5ca61ffd4bb54e9a7c) of the `VideoCapture` class and to the [VideoCaptureProperties](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.6/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704d). Specifically `CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `set()` method of the VideoCapture class allows one to jump to a specific frame and start reading from that point.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("file_name.avi")
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, index)
```

Would set the video reader to start reading at the frame specified by `index`, and this is zero based.

The `get()` method would then allow you to check what the current frame index is, `cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)` would return the current frame address.

All that is left is to convert the timestamps into frame indices, and to loop between the start and end frame, checking whether you want to read the frame or stop reading. The `get()` method can also be used to read the total number of frames in a file, which will help with this.

Looking at the options for `get()` and `set()`, you could probably also use `cv.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` which is the current position in the video in milliseconds.

Comment: thanks for replying, but how would you convert timestamps to frames?

Comment: If you know the length of the video, and the number of frames, you could scale a timestamp to a frame number. Looking at the opencv documentation though, you're better off using `cv.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` both to set, and to get. This takes/returns a timestamp in milliseconds.

Comment: can u please tell me how to play the audio too, from that particular frame.

Comment: OpenCV is to the best of my knowledge unable to process the audio side of video files. You should probably investigate use of ffmpeg either as a standalone tool, or as a library as it will be more useful.